# Kendo Autocomplete configuration

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, autocomplete

I am trying Kendo autocomplete for the first time & having some issues while configuring.

- It works fine if i type 3 characters & let's say if i remove text
  completely from multiselect field, autocomplete feature doesn't work
  until i refresh the page.
- when we type more than 3 characters filtering calls MVC controller again & i want to avoid this so there wouldn't be many server calls.(In other words server call should happen only if user types 3 characters & rest of the filtering should happen on the client side)

Here is the code

```js
                $scope.selectOptions = {
                    placeholder: "Search...",
                    noDataTemplate: 'No data found',
                    dataTextField: "Name",
                    dataValueField: "Id",
                    valuePrimitive: false,
                    autoBind: false,
                    //filter: "contains",
                    animation: {
                        close: {
                            effects: "fadeOut zoom:out",
                            duration: 300
                        },
                        open: {
                            effects: "fadeIn zoom:in",
                            duration: 300
                        }
                    },
                    minLength: 3,
                    dataSource: {
                        //type: "odata",
                        serverFiltering: true,
                        serverPaging: true,
                        pageSize: 10,
                        filtering: function (e) {
                            var filter = e.filter;

                            if (!filter.value) {
                                //prevent filtering if the filter does not value
                                e.preventDefault();
                            }
                        },
                        transport: {

                            read: {
                                url: "/Configuration/GetData",
                                type: 'GET',
                                dataType: 'json'
                            },
                            parameterMap: function (options, type) {
                               if (type === "read") {
                                    var paramMap = kendo.data.transports.odata.parameterMap(options);
                                    delete paramMap.$inlinecount; // <-- remove inlinecount parameter.
                                    delete paramMap.$format; // <-- remove format parameter.
                                   // return paramMap;

                                    return { searchCriteria: options.filter.filters[0].value};
                                } 
                            },
                            schema: {
                                data: function (data) {
                                    return data; // <-- The result is just the data, it doesn't need to be unpacked.
                                },
                                total: function (data) {
                                    return data.length; // <-- The total items count is the data length, there is no .Count to unpack.
                                }
                            }
                        }


                    }
                };
            $scope.selectedIds = [1, 2];
```

```html
<select kendo-multi-select k-options="selectOptions" k-ng-model="selectedIds" k-min-length="3" class="form-control"></select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the Autocomplete's dataSource to a localDataSource that doesn't fetch anything from the server:

```
const externalDataSource = {...} // what you have now
const localDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource()
externalDataSource.bind("change", (e) => {
    localDataSource.data(e.sender.data())
})
externalDataSource.read()
```

Comment: Thanks. Since Kendo doesn't have dataValueField, i am trying to use the following method to grab the selected id's but it doesn't seem to work if i select more than one option in Multiselect. How do i get multiple id's ?

Comment: select: function(e) {
                               e.dataItem.Id
                               }

Comment: I don't use Angular, but there is a valueField: https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/multiselect/value-binding/#toc-object-values